# Fiber-connected Lie subgroupoid of a Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}\rightrightarrows M$ is open

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathcal{G}\rightrightarrows M$, which has possible disconnected $\mathbf{t},\mathbf{s}$-fibers and disconnected set of units. We denote by $\mathcal{G}^{(0)}$ the union of all connected components of the fibers $\mathbf{t}^{-1}(x)$ containing the unit $1_x$. Then $\mathcal{G}^{(0)}$ is supposed to be an open Lie subgroupoid of $\mathcal{G}$, so they have the same Lie algebroid asscoiated to them. I wanted to show that this set is indeed open, so I wanted to construct an open neighbourhood $U$ around every $g\in \mathcal{G}^{(0)}$ such that any $h\in U$ can be connected to $1_{\mathbf{t}(h)}$ by a parth completely lying in $\mathbf{t}^{-1}(\mathbf{t}(h))$, but I don't really know what to work with.

Comment: Please do not delete questions immediately after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find your question useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. My approach does not use paths, so I don't know how much use of it is to you.

To show that $\mathcal{G}^{(0)}$ is open, I want to construct an open around each $g\in \mathcal{G}^{(0)}$. I think it is sufficient to construct an open $U$ around the identity section $\textbf{u}(M)\subseteq \mathcal{G}$ such that it is contained in $\mathcal{G}^{(0)}$ and then move around this open to any point in $\mathcal{G}^{(0)}$ using left multiplication.

Since $\textbf{s}:\mathcal{G}\rightarrow M$ is a submersion we can apply the local normal form theorem (see the wiki page on submersions). This says that for each $g\in\mathcal{G}$ there is an open neighborhood $U_g$ of $g$ together with an open neighborhood $V_{\textbf{s}(g)}$ of $\textbf{s}(g)$ such that $\textbf{s}(U_g)=V_{\textbf{s}(g)}$. Applying this to the identity $g=1_x\in\mathcal{G}^{(0)}$ we obtain open neighborhoods $U_x$ around all the units $1_x\in\mathcal{G}^{(0)}$. (I guess these $U_x$ need not be connected, but maybe they always intersect the s-fibers $s^{-1}(x)$ in a connected set, so $U_x\subseteq\mathcal{G}^0$.) Our neighborhood around the identity section $\textbf{u}(M)\subseteq\mathcal{G}$ is then $$U=\bigcup_{x\in M}U_x.$$

(If you have a more formal argument for why we can move $U$ around $\mathcal{G}^{(0)}$ please post this, because I would like to know. The same for why $U_x\subseteq\mathcal{G}^0$.)

Comment: This was the first idea that I had in mind as well, and we can translate the point $\mathbf{1}_x$ to $g$ by left multiplication (in fact we can move all of $U\cap\mathbf{t}^{-1}(x)$), but it is a bit tough to move the other fibers, and I didnt really see how to move them